# Android chat application server suggestion?

Tags: android

I have to create a chat app for android

1. which chat server i can use?
2. is there any free chat servers available for android platform ?

Comment: Investigate XMPP servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used OpenFire to host a server for an Android chat application I built. Did a lot of research and that was the best option I found. Works really well.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

It uses XMPP/Jabber as protocol. I then used ASmack as framework for Android.

https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack

Comment: You install OpenFire on a computer that is connected to the internet. You then use the framework in your Android application to connect to the url of that server.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as a "Chat server for Android". You can use any web server you want that suits your requirements to host your backend on.
2. If you want scale, you'll have to pay for good services. Most web platforms like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/) etc have free plans upto a certain limit but sooner or later they will cost you.
3. If you don't want to write your own backend, you can use a service like [Parse](https://parse.com/) or [StackMob](https://www.stackmob.com/).

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can used online data base to store chat data .

https://www.parse.com/

Comment: parse is now back4app - but that has nothing to do with chat. You simply use PubNub for chat -like apps these days.  it's one line of code.